# Booking Ticket with 2 first Name through travel agents

Tags: air-travel, tickets, bookings

I am planning to buy a ticket for myself and my fiancee and I noticed that on her passport she has 2 given names and the second name is quite big like 10 letters. She has an american passport

It is something Like that 
Given Names AAAAAA BBBBB-BBBBBBB
SurName CCCCCCC

I was wondering if it will be a problem if I use only the first letter of her second name or should I just skip the second name?
Or should I tell the travel agent full name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**: You should tell the travel agent the full name. It's probably fine if you don't, but why settle for probably?

Names on airline tickets are often written in somewhat odd ways (eg *LASTNAME, FIRSTNAMETITLE*) and realistically the chances that you'll face any problems if you ignore or abbreviate the middle name are low.

But having said that: you gain absolutely nothing by doing so (except, I suppose, the effort of typing out your fiancee's middle name - which is far less effort than you've already spent submitting this question), and without knowing all the details of the trip you're planning we can't be totally sure that you're not flying with an operator or to a destination where having the correct (full) name *does* make a difference. Tell the travel agent the full name and you won't have to worry about that.

Comment: @Student in that case I'd be even more confident that you'll face no trouble without the middle name. Nevertheless, I'd still advise you to give the travel agent your fiancee's full name, and I really don't understand why it seems you'd to prefer to do otherwise. It *probably* won't cause problems if you don't give the middle name, but it *definitely* won't cause problems if you do give it.